# bash: /opt/ros/lunar/setup.bash: No such file or directory

Tags: ros, bashrc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Users;

I installed Ros Lunar distro before. After that I decided to switch to Kinetic. Therefore, I remove Lunar from the terminal, and then installed ROS Kinetic. However; I still have this problem: "bash: /opt/ros/lunar/setup.bash: No such file or directory"

I can not find where is this file. In the opt directory, there is no lunar, because I already deleted it. And I can't find that comment file  to fix that source file that is reading that comment.

Any advice?
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278188/bash:-/opt/ros/lunar/setup.bash:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [ercan_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/33033/ercan_ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-12-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see whether #q253480 helps.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ercan_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/33033/ercan_ros/) on 2017-12-26**:
Dear  @gvdhoorn;
Yes, I already searched before and I already seen that page. However, even though I tried what it was said there, it didn't fix the problem.
Later I found this, and it fixed the problem:
Dear @gvdhoorn, thank you for your response.